# R - recursion over columns of data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am given data-table, where the (i+1)-th column depends on the previous one and needs to be calculated recursively. The header of data-table consists of a sequence starting from 0.`

```
   0  1  2  3
1: 1 NA NA NA
2: 2 NA NA NA
3: 3 NA NA NA
```

Accessing the columns by the index, e.g. `dt[,..2]` makes the code IMHO the most readable. Yet, this apparently cannot be used when trying to assign:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table("0"=c(1,2,3),"1"=c(NA,NA,NA),"2"=c(NA,NA,NA),"3"=c(NA,NA,NA))
x <- c(0.01, 0.02, 0.015)

for (u in 1:3){
               v<- u+1
               dt[,..v] <- dt[,..u]*(1+x[u])
 }
```

This yields the following error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, , ..v, value = list(`0` = c(1.01, 2.02,  : object '..v' not found
```

Update: Thanks @IceCreamToucan for the answer. However, I have just posted a simple example to illustrate my general issue. Due to the higher complexity of my actual code, I probably will have to stick to a for-loop. So I look to a solution, to recursively access and assign the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `lapply` and `cumprod`. I renamed the varibles because I'm not sure how to deal with numeric column names. Also see comments for an `outer` and `cumprod` option.

```
setnames(dt, names(dt), paste0('v', names(dt)))
dt[, names(dt)[-1] := lapply(cumprod(1 + x), '*', v0)][]

#    v0   v1     v2       v3
# 1:  1 1.01 1.0302 1.045653
# 2:  2 2.02 2.0604 2.091306
# 3:  3 3.03 3.0906 3.136959
```

You can also do it this way

```
for (u in 0:2){
  v <- u+1
  dt[, as.character(v) := get(as.character(u))*(1 + x[u + 1])] 
}

dt[]

#    0    1      2        3
# 1: 1 1.01 1.0302 1.045653
# 2: 2 2.02 2.0604 2.091306
# 3: 3 3.03 3.0906 3.136959
```

Comment: Or use a matrix `dt[, outer(\`0\`, cumprod(1+c(0,x)))]` (fwiw, numeric and other exotic col names can be accessed with a backtick, but I'd recommend renaming as you do here anyways)